# Difference between #if and if clause?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C ( I'm working on iOS SDK ), I can use the following 2 ways to branch conditions:

**Method 1**

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // Branch A
# elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // Branch B
# endif
```

**Method 2**

```
if(TARGET_OS_IPHONE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
    // Branch A
} else {
    // Branch B
}
```

What is the difference between the 2 methods? I noticed that Xcode doesn't detect coding errors within branches in Method 1.

Note: `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` & `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` are 2 macros to identify device types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is a condition within your code; it is checked when your code runs.

`#if` is a precompiler directive; it dictates whether code is ejected before the compiler even sees it. (As you rightly say, Xcode is able to make this decision without even compiling your code, so it eliminates ejected code from consideration, such as code completion.)

It's partly a matter of what kind of thing is being decided, obviously. If this is a decision that *can* be made before compilation - i.e., it's something about the compilation/building process itself - then `#if` is reasonable. If it isn't something that can be decided until the code is actually running, then of course `#if` is impossible.

Comment: I see. In which case we should use precompiler directive instead of condition clause? I found myself more comfortable using condition clause, as it spots errors.

Comment: Precompiler directive is appropriate to make sure that certain lines of code just don't appear under some circumstances. For example, some people use `#if DEBUG` to wrap `NSLog` calls, so that there is no danger of logging in the final build.

Comment: Also I use it to experiment with, or to demonstrate, completely independent ways of doing the same thing, as here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch02p070filters/ch15p419filters/ViewController.m

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, due to the conditional compilation, the preprocessor directives can accomplish something that is just impossible using a regular `if` statement. For instance, try using an `if` statement to achieve this admittedly slightly artificial example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define USE_LONG

int main(void) {

#ifdef USE_LONG
    long my_var = 0;
#else
    int my_var = 0;
#endif

    printf("Value plus 5 is %ld\n", my_var + 5l);

    return 0;
}
```

You'll get an undeclared identifier if you try to do this with an `if` statement, since the declaration of `my_var` will be limited to the scope of the containing block in either case.

A common use case for these is making programs more portable, by selecting different blocks of code to compile based on whether `#ifdef WINDOWS` or `#ifdef MAC` or whatever turn out to be true, when those systems have, say, different and incompatible function calls to achieve the same end.